# Search format not matching taxonomy query

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, search

I have inherited some code in this project. This search works. I can click on each individual taxonomy and see the results displayed on my page. However, I would like this to extend the search rather than just perform a new search i.e. I am trying to find an event in a region and the category of event and the age group.
`?region=102&category=8&agegroup=74`

```
$taxonomy_query = array();
if( isset( $_GET['region'] ) && $_GET['region'] ){
$taxonomy_region_query = array( 'taxonomy' => 'region', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => $_GET['region'] );
$taxonomy_query[] = $taxonomy_region_query;
}
if( isset( $_GET['category'] ) && $_GET['category'] ){
$taxonomy_cat_query = array( 'taxonomy' => 'event_category', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => $_GET['category'] );
$taxonomy_query[] = $taxonomy_cat_query;
}
if( isset( $_GET['age_groups'] ) && $_GET['age_groups'] ){
$taxonomy_age_query = array( 'taxonomy' => 'age_groups', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => $_GET['age_groups']);
$taxonomy_query[] = $taxonomy_age_query;
}
if( $taxonomy_region_query & $taxonomy_cat_query & $taxonomy_age_query ){
$taxonomy_query['relation'] = 'AND';
}
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => array("event"),
        'post_status'    => "publish",
        'meta_key'       => "sc_event_date",
        'orderby'        => "sc_event_date",
        'meta_query'     => $search_query,
        'tax_query'      => $taxonomy_query,
        'order'              => "ASC",
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        );
$event_query = new WP_Query($args);`
```

Edit:

Right, I've changed the way I perform the search, I'm now using radio buttons.

```
<?php foreach( $regions as $region ) : ?>
<label><input type="radio" name="?region=<?php echo $region->slug;?>" /><span><?php echo $region->name;?></span></input></label><br />
<?php endforeach;?>
```

I have one for region, category and agegroup. I have a new problem. I have successfully enabled the search to add on each new term, but my search query now looks like this:

```
?%3Fregion%3Dborders=on&%3Fcategory%3Dadventure-races=on&%3Fcategory%3Dadult=on
```

The taxonomy query won't recognise this format, it will only show me the results if they appear in this format in the url:

```
?region=borders&category=adventure-races&agegroup=adult
```

How do I enable my search to output the same format as the taxomony query search? As far as I gather its the %3F, %3F and =on that are causing the problem. So frustrated. I'm almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with my radio buttons.

```
<?php foreach( $regions as $region ) : ?>
<label><input type="radio" name="region" value="<?php echo $region->slug;?>" /><span><?php echo $region->name;?></span></input></label><br />
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

I have solved this problem by giving the radio buttons a name and value and not using any symbols in that name or value. It really was that simple.